# How can I automatically kill sleeping processes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I notice always sleeping dead processes from MySQL remote logins using Navicat. They regularly hang up my DB. I have to login and kill them manually always. Is there a better automatic way to monitor sleeping processes and kill them after a while?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure MySQL [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) to automatically close such connections.

Comment: MySQL is on a host provider and I am not able to modify the general settings. What can I do in such case? Thanks